# Python infinite product generator

Tags: python, combinatorics, python-3.x

I have the code below to get an infinite generator of the products of an iterable (e.g. for the iterable "ABC" it should return

A, B, C, AA, AB, AC, BA, BB, BC, CA, CB, CC, AAA, AAB, AAC etc.

```
for product in (itertools.product("ABC", repeat=i) for i in itertools.count(0)):
    for each_tuple in product:
        print(each_tuple)
```

How would I remove the nested for loop, or is there a better approach?

Comment: you can write `itertools.count()` instead of `.count(0)`. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you effectively have 3 nested loops including the generator comprehension, which you can reduce to two just by simplifying:

```
def get_products(string):
    for i in itertools.count(0):
        for product in itertools.product(string, repeat=i):
            yield product
```

Or if you are intent on putting it in a single line, use `chain`:

```
products_generator = itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.product("ABC", repeat=i)
                                                   for i in itertools.count(0))
```